# How to make neat url for multiple pages and multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have two pages like,

1. localhost/project/page1/a/b
2. localhost/project/page2/c/d

I tried to get the url's separately by using the .htaccess below

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page1.php?url1=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page2.php?url2=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I get the parameters using the $_GET method on their respective pages and i got the results as below,

```
Array
(
    [id] => page1/a/b.php/a/b
)
```

When i tried to visit the **page2** i got the same result above.
Help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Your first rule applies to any url, so second rules is not reached. Add some differences to them

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can i add the difference

Comment: Something like `^(.+)page(\d)(.+)$ page$2?url$2=$3`

Comment: I did something like this -> RewriteRule ^(.+)page1(\d)(.+)$ page1$2 ?url$2=$3 [L,QSA]. I get internal server error

Comment: No space between `$2 ?`